# How could calculate the excel data by using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an assignment to do for my boring online class and I couldn't come out with an idea to do this thing. I'm told to calculate the ratio of four columns with this formula ratio = weight/height*length*width. Bu i'm bad at using microsoft excel and ironically we haven't learnt anything related to that. So I remembered that there is a python library which works with excel sheets. So how could I calculate this ratio = Weight/Height*Width*Length by using openpyxl for every single row in this excel sheet easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never used openpyxl library I tried to find a solution to your problem. If the spreadsheet you're working on looks like the one below then you should be able to work with this script.

[Sample spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvGo1.png)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Modify filename and sheet name where the data is
workbook_filename = 'workbook.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

wb = load_workbook(workbook_filename)
ws = wb[sheet_name]

# If the data is stored differently in your file, you have to modify
# this loop to suit your needs
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 2, max_row = 3, max_col = 5):
    row[4].value = row[0].value / (row[1].value * row[2].value * row[3].value)

wb.save('result.xlsx')
```